# PHP part of text to be bold

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link(esc_html__('&laquo; Older Posts','OSC')) ?></div>
```

Is there any way how can I force the text "Older Posts" to be **`bold`** in this code rather than use external css file?

Comment: wrap it in `<strong>...</strong>`.

Comment: `<strong>` is for semantics, not for display.  It's a coincidence that your browser displays text inside that element as bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="align left" style="font-weight:bold"><?php next_posts_link(esc_html__('&laquo; Older Posts','OSC')) ?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats it. I forgot I could to it in div, jesus. I tried that in the php code. Will accept as answer once the system lets me.

Comment: Rather than inline css, if you don't want to use an external file, you can put the css inside of `<style>` tags in the `<head>` of your document.  It would make changing it at a later point easier if you have multiple instances.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div class="align left" ><b><?php next_posts_link(esc_html__('&laquo; Older Posts','OSC')) ?></b></div>
```